# How to resolve 500 Internal Server Error on /transactions/<hash>/operations?

Tags: stellar-core, horizon

My node returns an error when I query the `/operations` endpoint in horizon.

```
curl http://127.0.0.1:8000/transactions/73ce2618095d2c17bdaf08a6a6617cef549f974b1619f03b84eb46747e5e4eb0/operations
{
  "type": "https://stellar.org/horizon-errors/server_error",
  "title": "Internal Server Error",
  "status": 500,
  "detail": "An error occurred while processing this request.  This is usually due to a bug within the server software.  Trying this request again may succeed if the bug is transient, otherwise please report this issue to the issue tracker at: https://github.com/stellar/go/services/horizon/internal/issues. Please include this response in your issue."
```

Has anyone come across this, and is there a fix? I am running older code, so that could be it:

```
  "horizon_version": "v0.13.1",
  "core_version": "v9.2.0",
  "history_latest_ledger": 19653047,
  "history_elder_ledger": 132,
  "core_latest_ledger": 19653049,
  "network_passphrase": "Public Global Stellar Network ; September 2015",
  "protocol_version": 9
```

Comment: What does the horizon process report?

Comment: How do you actually check the horizon process? I'm only familiar with checking core and the db.

Comment: Good question! I just checked and I can't find where Horizon logs.

Comment: by default the logs are in syslog `/var/log/messages` but you can also specify your own log file via env variables or command line arguments when starting horizon, e.g. --log-file=/var/log/horizon.log